# Using lodash to map complex JSONs

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I'm trying to map data from one format to another and I'm having some hard time.

**FIRST ONE**

from:

```
  types: {
      one: [0.0954835843,6.054385,84.40238],
      two: [0.0954835843,6.054385,84.40238],
      three: [0.0954835843,6.054385,84.40238]
    },
```

to

```
    types: [
      [0.0954835843,6.054385,84.40238 , 'one'],
      [0.0954835843,6.054385,84.40238, 'two'],
      [0.0954835843,6.054385,84.40238, 'three']
    ],
```

**SECOND ONE**
match with ID, by getting data from two objects

```
          types:[{
            id:1, 
            data:[
                    [
                        'temp',
                        '46%',
                        '14.00',
                        '1388.68561604',
                        '1388.68561604',
                        '2018-02-12 18:21'

                    ],
                    [
                        'nottemp',
                        '46%',
                        '14.00',
                        '1388.68561604',
                        '1388.68561604',
                        '2018-02-12 18:21'

                    ],
               ] 
            },
            {
            id:2, 
            data:[
                    [
                        'temp',
                        '46%',
                        '14.00',
                        '1388.68561604',
                        '1388.68561604',
                        '2018-02-12 18:21'

                    ],
                    [
                        'nottemp',
                        '46%',
                        '14.00',
                        '1388.68561604',
                        '1388.68561604',
                        '2018-02-12 18:21'

                    ],
               ] 
            }]






data: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'sibling',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'parent',
        },
     ]
```

and end up with all the items from types.data in format like:

```
        [
                'temp',
                '46%',
                '14.00',
                '1388.68561604',
                '1388.68561604',
                '2018-02-12 18:21'
                'parent' //or sibling, depends on id

            ]
```

I actually have no idea how I can achive that with some mapping or filtering.
It's crazy hard for me to achive it without tons of modifiers and without creating few additional arrays in the process. Is there any way to optimize it?

**EDIT**
for the second issue I have:

```
   mapElement: function(){
        let that=this;
        return _.map(this.getTypesData,function(element){
          let data=[];
          let pairName = that.getFamily(element.id); //todo: matching id of Type with id of object with names
          element.data.forEach(function(element){
            data.push([
              pairName,
              element[0],
              element[1],
              element[2],
            ]);
          });
          return data;
        });
      }
```

Comment: Share some of your codes

Comment: @SatishKumar updated

Comment: Why not just use vanilla JS? No need for a library - will a vanilla solution work?

Comment: @CertainPerformance sure! No need for lodash if we can achive it with plain js, even better :)

Comment: For first one just use if yout dont need to support IE11 Object.values(  types: {
      one: [0.0954835843,6.054385,84.40238],
      two: [0.0954835843,6.054385,84.40238],
      three: [0.0954835843,6.054385,84.40238]
    }). Otherwise you can use the "for in" loop construct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## the 1st question:

super easy with `_.map`:

```
// Also handle case value is not array
types = _.map(types, (val, key) => _.isArray(val) ? v.concat(key) : [val].concat(key));
```

## the 2nd question:

I optimized for performance:

```
//clone to new object to avoid modifying original data
const cloneData = _.cloneDeep(data);

types = _.map(types, (val, key) => {
    const index = _.findIndex(cloneData, { id: val.id});
    val.data = _.map(val.data, (v)=> _.isArray(v) ?v.concat(cloneData[index].name) : [v].concat(cloneData[index].name));
    //remove when found id to shorten the array
    // if the types[].id is not unique, remove this
    cloneData.splice(index,1);

    return val;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```js
const input = {types: {
      one: [0.0954835843,6.054385,84.40238],
      two: [0.0954835843,6.054385,84.40238],
      three: [0.0954835843,6.054385,84.40238]
    },
}
const output = Object.keys(input.types).map((key,val) => {
  return [...input.types[key],key];
})
console.log(output);
```

1.Use Object.keys to get the keys of object (lodash, _.keys()).

2.

```
return [...input.types[key],key]
```

The above line can be split into (for better understanding),

```
const returnVal = _.clone(input.type[key]).push(key);
return returnVal
```

If you get the idea then you may try the 2nd one by your self.

Comment: You shouldn't use `let` unless you're going to reassign the variable - use `const` instead.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, just use `Object.entries` and append the key to the end:

```js
const obj = {
  types: {
    one: [0.0954835843, 6.054385, 84.40238],
    two: [0.0954835843, 6.054385, 84.40238],
    three: [0.0954835843, 6.054385, 84.40238]
  },
};
obj.types = Object.entries(obj.types)
  .map(([key, val]) => [...val, key]);
console.log(obj);
```

For the second one, you just need to `map` once, find the key + string in the data object, and return a map of the inner array, appending the found string:

```js
const types = [{
    id: 1,
    data: [
      [
        'temp',
        '46%',
        '14.00',
        '1388.68561604',
        '1388.68561604',
        '2018-02-12 18:21'

      ],
      [
        'nottemp',
        '46%',
        '14.00',
        '1388.68561604',
        '1388.68561604',
        '2018-02-12 18:21'

      ],
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    data: [
      [
        'temp',
        '46%',
        '14.00',
        '1388.68561604',
        '1388.68561604',
        '2018-02-12 18:21'

      ],
      [
        'nottemp',
        '46%',
        '14.00',
        '1388.68561604',
        '1388.68561604',
        '2018-02-12 18:21'

      ],
    ]
  }
];

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'sibling',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'parent',
  },
];

types.data = types.map(({ id, data: typesData }) => {
  const str = data.find(({ id: dataId }) => dataId === id).name;
  return typesData.map(arr => [...arr, str]);
});
console.log(types.data);
```

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
const newTypes1 = Object.keys(obj.types).map(t => {
  return [...obj.types[t], t];
});
```

Second:

```
types.forEach(t => {
  const name = data.find(function(x) { return x.id == t.id }).name;
  t.data.forEach(d => { d.push(name) });
});
```

**EDIT**: For the first one, a new array is created and for the second one, the name is pushed in the array so you keep the same object.